# Windows locks all mounted drives on hibernate

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a dual-boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu setup. I use Ext2Fsd to mount my Ubuntu root drive on Windows. In this state, if I hibernate Windows, both my Windows and Ubuntu drives are locked. Booting into Ubuntu allows read-only access to the root drive causing problems.

Is there a way to make Windows lock only the Windows drive on hibernate besides unmounting all other drives?

I have other shared drives for data sharing and stuff, but I really need to access my Ubuntu partition from Windows every once in a while and its a pain to unmount before hibernating(or auto-hibernate).

Comment: There is a good reason for this behavior. When Windows goes into hibernation it is important that all drives it has access to remain unmodified. Otherwise data corruption is likely. Do not attempt to evade this protection. Booting into another OS while a Windows OS is in hibernation is problematic and best avoided.

Comment: If I understand correctly, hibernation stores OS and application data state(basically main memory state) to disk and shuts down, right? This should close file descriptors or does it keep them open? Data files from the non-OS drives should be flushed and closed. Is that done?

Comment: I believe the file cache and other things are flushed to disk only for external drives. For local drives there is a reasonable expectation that the drive contents will remain as it was left before hibernation. And under normal circumstances this will be true. Windows boot manager will not allow booting into another OS while one is in hibernation. Windows applications can behave unpredictably when the files they were using are modified without their knowledge. Applications aren't advised of hibernation. It is just a mere pause in activity.